# Is there any way to stop PS4 from downloading multiplayer portion of a game?

Tags: ps4

I have just finished installing Assassins Creed IV Blackflag for the PS4 (singleplayer). Now I just want to play the single player mode and skip the multiplayer.

When I enter the game screen, it shows that the multiplayer is being downloaded (22% installed and about 11 of 22 GB's in total), and since I am on a relatively slow DSL connection with a strict bandwidth cap on top of that, is there any way to permanently stop the multiplayer download? I don't want the download resuming everytime I turn on the console or play a game.

Comment: You could play offline.

Comment: Yes, disconnect from the wireless router or unplug the ethernet cord.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. It's part of the game.
You could cancel the download from the menu I guess but it's probably just gonna restart the download the next time you start the game.